# Is Sitemesh 2.4 release broken?

Tags: java, decorator, servlet-filters, sitemesh

We've recently upgraded one of our projects. This involves new versions of JARs also.

Sitemesh was one of them. We updated from 2.2.1 to 2.4.2. **Things stopped working.**

We had a custom filter extend Sitemesh's `PageFilter` which now does not work because in v2.4 `PageFilter` extends `SiteMeshFilter` which does not expose the same methods (the ones we were overriding).

OK, no biggy, we'll just change our code to match, but then I saw this in the source code I downloaded from http://java.net/downloads/sitemesh/

```
/**
 * Core Filter for integrating SiteMesh into a Java web application.
 *
 * @author Joe Walnes
 * @author Scott Farquhar
 * @since SiteMesh 3
 */
public class SiteMeshFilter implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;
    private ContainerTweaks containerTweaks;
    private static final String ALREADY_APPLIED_KEY = "com.opensymphony.sitemesh.APPLIED_ONCE";
............
```

**@since SiteMesh 3?** This is v2.4.2. What 3?

Is the release corrupt or what? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using sitemesh 2.4.2 in one project and it works fine.

You can see that that change (which mentions Sitemesh 3) was done back in 2005 when they refactored the architecture to be compatible with sitemesh3. Here's the commit in [github](https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh2/commit/e7323c1b2527a59f438cfb64dbc674f90c42d8da).

I remember getting a similar impression when I was browsing the javadocs a few months ago :).

So the answer is: The jar is not corrupt, it's just the result of a crooked merge.